# Memory Leak in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks

I have a `Dialog Fragment` named `SignInDialogFragment` which is called from `HomeActivity`. When it is called, it presents username and password `EditText` fields and convey the input with `Interface` to related functions in `HomeActivity`.

When I call `SignInDialogFragment` from `HomeActivity` and then dismiss it without doing anything, LeakCanary warns me that there is a memory leak.

Here is how `SignInDialogFragment` is set in `HomeActivity`:

```
private val signInDialogFragment : SignInDialogFragment by lazy {
    SignInDialogFragment.newInstance(object: SignInDialogFragment.SignInDialogFragmentInterface {
        override fun onFinish() {
           // Do stuff
        }
        // Here are more interface functions
    })
}
```

What I discovered is when I don't set `SignInDialogFragment` with `lazy`, make it optional and nullify it in `HomeActivity's` `onPause` function, leak doesn't occur.

What I couldn't understand is why this leak is happening in the first place. Here a few things I tried:

-Instead of setting listener as an anonymous object (i.e., `object: SignInDialogFragment.SignInDialogFragmentInterface )`, I set it as an optional and nullify it in activity's `onPause` function; didn't work.

- I tried to nullify listener (i.e., `SignInDialogFragment.SignInDialogFragmentInterface` ) in the fragment dialog's `onPause` function; leak still occured.

Since I create a new instance of a `SignInDialogFragment` with static function:

```
companion object {
    fun newInstance(listener: SignInDialogFragmentInterface) : SignInDialogFragment {
        val dialogFragment = SignInDialogFragment()
        dialogFragment.listener = listener
        return dialogFragment
    }
}
```

I thought problem may be here but couldn't figure it out.

I am quite new to memory leaks and garbage collection, so I am hoping that I am not doing some obvious mistake.:)

Any idea what causes the leak? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the .hprof file which may help.

[signInDialogFragmentMemoryLeak.hprof](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/823000/signInDialogFragmentMemoryLeak.hprof)

Comment: You are not authorized to download .hprof file

Comment: Changed the link.

Comment: `Dialog`s are destroyed and should not be reused once dismissed. You're holding a hard reference to the `DialogFragment` even after it was dismissed, that's why error disappeared after you set it to null. Listener doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Pawel so shall I pass it as `WeakReference`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
private  var listener : SignInDialogFragmentInterface? =null

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listenrer = context as SignInDialogFragmentInterface

    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listenrer = null
    }
```

Now use listener.onfinish()

Comment: Hey Kishan, thanks for the answer. I tried as the way you suggest, but leak still persists according to LeakCanary.